# Installed google chrome beta but it shows stable version

Tags: google-chrome

First I uninstalled chrome using below command

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
```

Then I installed chrome beta on ubuntu 12.04 using below command

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-beta
```

It was successful installation. Now when I search for chrome I see my old stable version. 
What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Check your local apt-cache like so:

```
$ apt-cache policy google-chrome-{unstable,beta,stable}

google-chrome-unstable:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 31.0.1626.0-1
  Version table:
     31.0.1626.0-1 0
        500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages

google-chrome-beta:
  Installed: 30.0.1599.37-1
  Candidate: 30.0.1599.37-1
  Version table:
 *** 30.0.1599.37-1 0
        500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

google-chrome-stable:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 29.0.1547.65-r220622
  Version table:
     29.0.1547.65-r220622 0
        500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
```

Here we can see the three versions of Chrome, which are installed and what's available in whatever distribution.

If you're running Chrome and haven't restarted it since upgrading, do that. Restart Chrome.

If `chrome://chrome/` still tells you you're on a different version, check the output of `ps aux | grep chrome` (while it's running). You *should* see a load of instances of `/opt/google/chrome/chrome` running. We can check which package is providing that binary:

```
$ dpkg -S /opt/google/chrome/chrome
google-chrome-beta: /opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

If the path is different to `/opt/google/chrome/chrome`, do the above with the altered path. Whatever it is, it's interfering with your installation.

Comment: Please explain the use of the curly brackets in `apt-cache policy google-chrome-{unstable,beta,stable}` or where we can look it up.

Comment: @vasa1 It's a Bash expansion.. *How* it works isn't relevant to the question, only that it works.... But if you want to learn more, there's quite [a big topic on tldp.org on expansions](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html)